# How to pass a function with parameters with a function in python?

Tags: python

Consider this:

```
def function1():
   def nestedfunc(param1, **kw):
      logging.info("nested function %s" % kw) #error
   function2(nestedfunc("is called"), string="not default")


def function2(func, string="default"):
   try:
      #doing some setting
      func()
   finally:
      #reset back to setting
```

I am getting:

```
func()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I am assuming the func() is not passing parameters and it causes the error.

To clarify, the desire result is to be able to call func() with any number of parameters added.

Does anyone know what is the proper way to do it? Any advice would be thankful!

Comment: the desire result is to be able to call func() with any number of parameters added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `function2` recieves `func=None` because that's the (default) return value of `nestedfunc()`, which is called with the parameter `"is called"`. You could use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to 'freeze' some function's arguments:

```
from functools import partial

def function1():
   def nestedfunc(param1, **kw):
      logging.info("nested function %s" % kw) #error
   function2(partial(nestedfunc, "is called"), string="not default")
```

Comment: Very nice, `functool.partial` is the right way to go.

Answer (score 1):

`nestedfunc("is called")` is the value returned by the function call: `None`. You should pass `nestedfunc` to `function2` *without* calling it first.

If you want to pass a parameter to `nestedfunc`, pass it to `function2` first.

```
def function1():
   def nestedfunc(param1, **kw):
      logging.info("nested function %s" % kw) #error
   function2(nestedfunc, "is called", string="not default")


def function2(func, funcparam, string="default"):
   try:
      #doing some setting
      func(funcparam)
   finally:
      #reset back to setting
```

Comment: this is what i did, but my goal is to add the func() with any number of params. not sure if it is possible.

Comment: The other answer does what you want.